# NSURLSession GET Request: DidCompleteWithError - error is null

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, nsurlsession

currently I'm trying to switch from the deprecated NSUrlConnection to NSUrlSession.
What I try to achieve is to call an IIS Webservice via GET requests and then handle the XML answers.
I have two problems:

1. If the answer is too long the NSData object in DidReceiveData does not contain everything. The answer is cropped after 1036 characters.
2. After everything is done and while im already handling the received data (wether or not it was cropped), DidCompleteWithError is called. The "error" parameter in it is null so I have no idea why this is called and how to handle that. So even when I received all the data in DidReceiveData and everything is fine DidCompleteWithError is called.

Here is my code, every help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
public class WebserviceCallerIOS : IWebServiceCaller
    {
        private NSMutableUrlRequest request;
        public NSUrlSessionDataTask dataTask;
        private Action<bool, string> completed;
        private string antwort;
        private NSUrlSession session;
        public NSOperationQueue myQueue;

        public void Invoke(string sUrl)
        {
            session = null;
            antwort = null;
            completed = null;
            myQueue = new NSOperationQueue();

            session = NSUrlSession.FromConfiguration(NSUrlSessionConfiguration.DefaultSessionConfiguration, (INSUrlSessionDelegate)new SessionDelegate((erfolg, body) => { completed(erfolg, body); }), myQueue);
            completed += WebserviceCallerIOS_Completed;

            try
            {
                request = CreateNativePostRequest(sUrl);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                completed(false, "Error creating request: " + e);
            }

            dataTask = session.CreateDataTask(request);
            dataTask.Resume();
        }

        NSMutableUrlRequest CreateNativePostRequest(string url)
        {
            string converted = ((NSString)url).CreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NSStringEncoding.UTF8);
            var nsurl = NSUrl.FromString(converted);

            if (nsurl == null)
                throw new Exception("Invalid URL, could not create NSUrl from: '" + url + "'.");

            var req = new NSMutableUrlRequest(nsurl) {HttpMethod = "GET"};
            return req;
        }

private class SessionDelegate : NSUrlSessionDataDelegate, INSUrlSessionDelegate
        {
            private Action<bool, string> completed_callback;
            private NSData retData;
            private int status_code;

            public SessionDelegate(Action<bool, string> completed)
            {
                completed_callback = completed;
                retData = new NSData();
            }


            public override void DidReceiveResponse(NSUrlSession session, NSUrlSessionDataTask dataTask, NSUrlResponse response, Action<NSUrlSessionResponseDisposition> completionHandler)
            {
                var http_response = response as NSHttpUrlResponse;
                if (http_response == null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Received non HTTP url response: '{0}'", response);
                    status_code = -1;
                    return;
                }


                status_code = (int)http_response.StatusCode;

                if (status_code == 200)
            {
                completionHandler(NSUrlSessionResponseDisposition.Allow);
            }
            else 
            {
                completionHandler(NSUrlSessionResponseDisposition.Cancel);
            }
        }


            public override void DidCompleteWithError(NSUrlSession session, NSUrlSessionTask task, NSError error)
            {
                completed_callback(false, error?.LocalizedDescription);
            }


            public override void DidReceiveData(NSUrlSession session, NSUrlSessionDataTask dataTask, NSData data)
            {
                retData = data;
                dataTask.Suspend();
                Console.WriteLine(retData);
                completed_callback(true, retData.ToString());
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If the answer is too long the NSData object in DidReceiveData does not contain everything. The answer is cropped after 1036 characters.

`DidReceiveData`  will be triggered and return small data many times. You have to create global variable to store the data. But you mean the data is over 1036 characters at once?

> After everything is done and while im already handling the received data (wether or not it was cropped), DidCompleteWithError is called. The "error" parameter in it is null so I have no idea why this is called and how to handle that. So even when I received all the data in DidReceiveData and everything is fine DidCompleteWithError is called.

Whether the request succeed or not, `DidCompleteWithError`  is always called after receiving all data. The error `null` represents that you have a successful request.

Comment: Awesome! This works. I added a string variable "answerCache", in DidReceiveData I only append the received data to that variable. In DidCompleteWithError I check if error is null. If it is, I call my completed method and tell it that everything worked fine and pass it the whole answerCache variable.